# Matrix with offdiagonal entries

Tags: matrices

Could anyone help with latex script for?
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the provided answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `amsmath` package and do this

```
\[J_0=\begin{pmatrix}
        0&-1&\cdots&0&0\\
        1&0&&0&0\\
        \vdots&&\ddots&&\vdots\\
        0&0&\ldots&1&0
      \end{pmatrix}\]
```