# Latex matrix left entries

Tags: matrices

Could anyone give me advice on how to write such a matrix in latex?
[image]

Comment: Just write a normal matrix but leave some cells empty

Comment: Gallery: https://de.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/matrices . Package nicematrix: https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nicematrix/nicematrix.pdf . Matrix packages: https://www.ctan.org/topic/matrix

Comment: See your previous question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/639966/matrix-with-offdiagonal-entries

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matrix with offdiagonal entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/639966/matrix-with-offdiagonal-entries)

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\[
E_8 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 &   &   &   &   &   &  \\
1 & 2 & 1 &   &   &   &   &  \\
  & 1 & 2 & 1 &   &   &   &  \\
  &   & 1 & 2 & 1 &   &   &  \\
  &   &   & 1 & 2 & 1 &   & 1\\
  &   &   &   & 1 & 2 & 1 &  \\
  &   &   &   &   & 1 & 2 &  \\
  &   &   &   & 1 &   &   & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\]


\end{document}
```

[image]